# Does Android 13 remove mEventQueue in SurfaceFlinger.cpp?

Tags: android, surfaceflinger, android-13

how does surfaceflinger in Android 13 handle Refresh and Invalidate events without the mEventQueue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same question, so I checked the code. I found **the mEventQueue is replaced by the mScheduler.**

As you can see, the Scheduler now extends from MessageQueue:

```
Scheduler::Scheduler(ICompositor& compositor, ISchedulerCallback& callback, FeatureFlags features)
  : impl::MessageQueue(compositor), mFeatures(features), mSchedulerCallback(callback) {}
```

Therefore, the Scheduler can do the same thing. For example, The function `SurfaceFlinger::run()` which will be executed when SurfaceFlinger create has changed to be:

```cpp
    // AOSP 13
    void SurfaceFlinger::run() {
        mScheduler->run();
    }

    void Scheduler::run() {
        while (true) {
            waitMessage();
        }
    }

    // before
    void SurfaceFlinger::run() {
         while (true) {
             mEventQueue->waitMessage();
         }
     }
```